# Xpath to JSON - still needs tidying

Tags: json, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to get the table of data from [this website.](http://www.hydro.com.au/water/lake-levels) and serve it out as JSON.
I am taking my first steps with Yahoo Pipes/XPath, so apologies in advance for the noob Qs.

I have [a pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=4d618e6b0c29caa5c2a5d26573dbb7fd) that just uses an XPath expression:

> //table[1](http://www.hydro.com.au/water/lake-levels)/tbody/tr

Which gives me the following [JSON output](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=4d618e6b0c29caa5c2a5d26573dbb7fd&_render=json) (snippet, 1 of about 30 items):

```
"items": [{
            "td": [{
                "a": {
                    "href": "http:\/\/www.hydro.com.au\/system\/files\/water-storage\/Web_Lakes_AUGUSTA.pdf",
                    "content": "Lake Augusta"
                }
            },
            {
                "p": "2.58"
            },
            {
                "p": "Steady"
            }],
            "description": null,
            "title": null
        },
```

What I want to end up with is a flattened out version, something like this:

```
"items": [{
    {
        "href": "http:\/\/www.hydro.com.au\/system\/files\/water-storage\/Web_Lakes_AUGUSTA.pdf",
    },
    {
        "content": "Lake Augusta"
    },
    {
        "p": "2.58"
    },
    {
        "p": "Steady"
    }],
},
```

Can someone help me achieve this? Should I be doing more with the original XPath, or is there a particular processor within Pipes that will help me accomplish this?

Comment: XPath results reflect the original document structure. It's very difficult to select a group of nodes that is not completely disjunctive and yet doesn't reflect the document structure (i.e. like your desired output). I would recommend you pull out the JSON/JS object array the XPath gives you and then massage it in the client until it fits your needs. I believe you can also post-process it in Pipes itself, but doing it with XPath alone won't work.

Comment: You might also want to try [Kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com/), they are way ahead of Yahoo Pipes in terms of Website scaping.

Comment: For kicks, here is a clone of your pipe that shows you how to build the output you want: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d2fe64963964bf6636b58fb7b9814ef0

Comment: wow. Kimono looks amazing and your pipe is the answer! Please turn your comments into an answer so i can give you the credit. Thanks!

Comment: Setting up a working feed in Kimono took me less time than building the Yahoo pipe, but Pipes is still *a lot* more flexible and capable when it comes to manipulating and combining data, especially in cases not as straight-forward as this one.

Comment: @Tomalak IMO, using Kimono for the straight data scraping seems optimal, then you can just write a process that manipulates the raw data feed. That way, if the website ever changes their structure, the changes to accommodate should be easier since they'd be separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to select the data structure you want directly with XPath.

However, it's not difficult to manipulate selected data in Yahoo Pipes, for example by combining a "Loop" module with a "Item Builder" module.

[image: Yahoo Pipes Item Builder]

The result is a feed that looks like this:

```
{
    "count": 43,
    "value": {
        "title": "Hydro Tasmania Lake Levels",
        "description": "Hydro Tasmania Lake Levels\n\nfrom StackOverflow Question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23248288/18771",
        "link": "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d2fe64963964bf6636b58fb7b9814ef0",
        "pubDate": "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 06:12:35 +0000",
        "generator": "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/",
        "callback": "",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Lake Augusta",
                "link": "http://www.hydro.com.au/system/files/water-storage/Web_Lakes_AUGUSTA.pdf",
                "meters": "2.58",
                "comment": "Steady",
                "description": null
            },
            ... more ...
        ]
    }
}
```